# Django pagination over the page limit showing still last results neverending

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, serialization

I have a Django function based API that inputs page number and on each page the size of the page. Here is my code.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def attendance_all_get_list_by_page(request):
    # ----- YAML below for Swagger -----
    """
    description: attendance_all_get_list_by_page
    parameters:
      - name: page
        type: integer
        required: true
        location: form   
      - name: page_limit
        type: integer
        required: true
        location: form                   
    """
    attendance_list = Attendance.objects.all().order_by('id') 

    page = request.GET.get('page', request.POST['page'])
    paginator = Paginator(attendance_list, request.POST['page_limit'])

    try:
        attendances = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        attendances = paginator.page(request.POST['page'])
    except EmptyPage:
        attendances = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    serializer = AttendanceSerializer(list(attendances), many=True)
    data = serializer.data[:]
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

my serializer:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ("id", "username")

class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('id','employee','created_at')
```

Imagine I had attendance record of

```
16,17,18,19
```

So for example with page=2 page_limit=2, it will show the following (this should be the last page of 4 records)

```
[
  {
    "id": 18,
    "employee": {
      "id": 16,
      "username": "haha"
    },
    "created_at": "2017-12-28T03:29:29.698339Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "employee": {
      "id": 16,
      "username": "haha"
    },
    "created_at": "2017-12-28T03:38:53.639749Z"
  }
]
```

if I did (page=3 page_limit=2) or (page=10 page_limit=2), it will still show

```
[
  {
    "id": 18,
    "employee": {
      "id": 16,
      "username": "haha"
    },
    "created_at": "2017-12-28T03:29:29.698339Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "employee": {
      "id": 16,
      "username": "haha"
    },
    "created_at": "2017-12-28T03:38:53.639749Z"
  }
]
```

the expected result should be

```
[]
```

Whats wrong with my pagination, something is affecting over the last page. I want so that the last page should show the last page result but after that it should be empty record lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You catch EmptyPage and return last page content. So if you are out of range you will get second page everytime.
You need to return empty list in this case:

```
except EmptyPage:
    attendances = []
```